# Python - Dynamically add new functions to a class in a structured way

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, structure

I have a basic class with some variables and objects stored like:

```
class Human():
    arms = Arms()
    legs = Legs()
    head = Head()
```

and I want too add functions to this class dynamically. For example something like:

```
class Swim():
    def moveArms(self):
        self.arms related stuff

    def breathe(self):
        self.head related stuff
```

and then I want to give this Swim class to human in this example so that a function like `learnSwim` can just pass the functions to class `Human` or any other arbitrary class like `Dog` etc. as long as they have `Arms` and `Head`.

But if I have a class like that is not compatible with my initial class, like below:

```
class Fly():
    def flapWings:
       do stuff with self.wings()
```

and I try to pass this class to `Human`, I would like it to be incompatible in assessment. Like `learnFly(human_instance)` should fail because `Human` has no wings. It shouldn't pass a `flapWings` function and `Human` only realizes this wont work upon function call.

I guess I could do:

```
def learnSwim(instance):
    if instance.arms is not None and instance.head is not None:
         instance.moveArms = Swim.moveArms
         instance.breathe = Swim.breathe
    else:
         raise Exception("No arms or head! I guess I'll just drown")

def learnFly(instance):
    if instance.wings is not None:
         instance.flapWings = Fly.flapWings
    else:
         raise Exception("Have no wings but you never know!")
```

so my question is, is there a more native/pythonic/simpler/conventional way to achieve this?

Comment: inheritance classess will help you to solve your problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python

Comment: I know this for defining classes, but never saw an example of this being done dynamically (so that we dont initially know which classes will be passed to an instance of `Human` class)

Comment: I think the idea of adding methods to a class dynamically is fundamentally wrong. Your idea of having separate classes is probably the best we can do here. I would use a list of objects which are instances of those classes thus containing the methods, passed to human, and checked against the human's attributes (does it have wings, does it have arms, etc) to see if the human should "learn" that ability.

Comment: Another thing that might help is, actually I want to use this to have replaceable modules within class that have the same input output relationship but the way they handle things are different. (so that `Human` will have `Swim` but I would like to plug in or out which style of `Swim` functions he will have). In either way it is a matter of design choice and not an absolute must I guess.